# If “credevo che vi importava di più della vostra amica che di" were to be rewritten in a formal register, should the subjunctive be used (importasse)?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, formal

I was reading the Harry Potter books in Italian (my first in the language), and in the Prisoner of Azkaban, Hagrid says to Harry and Ron "[...] credevo che a voi due vi importava di più della vostra amica che di una scopa o di un topo".

If the phrase were to be rewritten in a formal register, should the past subjunctive ("credevo che [...] vi *importasse* di più") be used instead of the *imperfetto*?

Comment: It *always* wants the subjunctive.

Comment: As you surely know, Hagrid notoriously speaks a broken English in the original, and this is apparently how they tried to reproduce it in Italian.

Comment: Thanks! Apart from that, is the sentence correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the correct (meaning “standard in modern Italian”) form of this sentence would be the one with the subjunctive mood, as is usual with verbs expressing an opinion, a belief etc. For instance, *Credo che tu abbia ragione* or *Pensavo che non volessi venire*.

Also notice that another issue in Hagrid's (Italian) sentence is the reduplication of *a voi*/*vi*. Normally this is frowned upon: you'd either say *credevo che a voi importasse...* or *credevo che vi importasse...*